# Azure Key Vault. How it works?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-keyvault

Hey can someone explain me how Azure Key Vault works because I have some doubts.
When we want to avoid putting a connection string in our code we can use a key vault. But if we want to call this key vault we have to put (hardcode) Vault, ClientId, Thumbprint (if we use certificate) etc. So it makes nonsense for me. Can someone explain me why is it good practice to use it? Please be understanding and thank you for any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a very good question :)

This is commonly known as a bootstrapping problem.
To access the secret store, we need to authenticate, but we need a secret for that!

If you run on Azure, the best solution in my opinion is to use Managed Identities.
This allows your app running in e.g. App Service to authenticate to services like Key Vault without storing any secrets in your app configuration or code.

You can read more about them in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview

Services that support Managed Identities: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities.

Comment: So I should override a appsettings (with Vault, ClientId etc) using a pipeline (production) or secrets (dev) for example in Azure DevOps?

Comment: What we do is set secrets in DevOps, they get added to Key Vault as secrets, and then we use the Key Vault configuration provider in ASP.NET Core to load the secrets into configuration (in-memory) at application startup.

Comment: @juunas is it possible to programmatically save to key vault. for example we have api integrations, and thinking to use key vault to store access keys for customer accounts in key vaults instead of database now. so is it possible that in our integration code when we get the keys through authorization to store them in keyvault and then get the keys from key vault instead of database?

Comment: Yes, you can use the Key Vault SDK for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/overview/azure/Security.KeyVault.Secrets-readme

Comment: @juunas thanks will have a look